# I would like to create a list of values from a rows within a dataframe, and delete the first 2 elements

Tags: python, pandas, list, plot

I am trying to plot time vs pressure.

Inside a loop I match two names together and try to create a list from the row that matches the name and delete the first 2 elements.

I have matched the names and created an empty list, appended the values at the corresponding index to that list and tried deleting the first 2 elements.

```
#Here is my vr dataframe
# wells,date,t-15,t0,t15,t30,t45,t60,t75,t90,t105
# RDVE0099,28/06/2019,-56.7,-56.9,-33.0,-27.1,-24.1,-20.9,-20.4,-19.6,-18.8
# RDVE0076,28/06/2019,-56.6,-57.0,-47.7,-47.6,-46.8,-41.4,-40.1,-39.2,36.5
# RDVE0088,28/06/2019,-57.1,-57.0,-49.9,-45.0,-42.3,-41.4,41.2,52.3,23.32

# I create a list to loop through

ewells = ['RDVE0089','RDVE0099']

for i in ewells:
    columnSeriesObj = vr['wells']
    xvals = [-15,0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180,195,210,225,240]
    for index, item in enumerate(columnSeriesObj.values):
        if item == i:
            g = []
            g.append(vr.iloc[index])
            del g[0]
            del g[1]
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
            ax7 = plt.plot(xvals,str(g),marker='o',color = 'black')
            plt.title('Vacuum Recovery Test Results')
            plt.legend()

#output so far:
[wells      RDVE0099
date     28/06/2019
-15           -56.7
0             -56.9
15              -33
30            -27.1
45            -24.1
60            -20.9
75            -20.4
90            -19.6
105           -18.8
120           -18.1
135           -17.4
150           -16.8
165           -16.3
180           -15.8
195           -15.4
210             -15
225           -14.7
240           -14.3
Name: 0, dtype: object]
<class 'list'>
```

I would like a list of the values in the right hand column that I can plot against the xvals list.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the output? A dataframe?

Comment: Yes, the list that is shown as the current output comes from a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

to transfrom a series (column) to a list apply the function:

```
pd.series.tolist()
```

this could work also for a row:

```
pd.df.loc[0].tolist()
```

Otherwise try a loop (for example i transform the first row in a list):

```
v=[]
for i in range(pd.loc[0].size):
    v.append(pd.iloc[0,i])
```

hope this helps,
Giulio